# Connect to a Google Cloud SQL Postgres DB over SSL using psycopg2

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, google-cloud-platform, psycopg2

I did not have a clue about encryption until today so please pardon me if my question is to basic.

I have a GCP SQL instance that is set up for Postgres with SSL encryption. I have created a client certificate on GCP and dowloaded and stored the:

- **server-ca.pem**
- **client-cert.pem**
- **client-key.pem**

files in my computer.

I am trying to connect to the remote DB using psycopg2 in python3.6 (installed using conda). I have checked the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) for establishing the connection and apparently the above files need to be used so that I can establish the connection. In specific in the `psycopg2.connect()` function I use the arguments:

- `sslmode='verify-ca'`
- `sslcert=[local path of client-cert.pem file]`
- `sslkey=[local path of client-key.pem file]`
- `sslrootcert=[local path of server-ca.pem file]`

Apparently there will be an error because according to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html) the the above files need to end in the following formats: `.crt` , `.key`.

After my research I found out that I (maybe) have to use `openssl` to generate the `.crt` and `.key` formats. How am I supposed to do that?

If I convert the `.pem` files and pass the converted ones to the `psycopg2.connect()` will I be able to connect to my remote DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use openssl to convert the .pem files to .crt and .key files

First of all using command prompt/ terminal go to the directory where the .pem files are stored.

For the .crt file type:

- `openssl x509 -in client-cert.pem -out ssl-cert.crt`
- `openssl x509 -in server-ca.pem -out ca-cert.crt`

For the .key file type:

- `openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out ssl-key.key`

and finally for connecting to the DB using `psycopg2.connect()` simply pass the file path of the above files to the `sslcert , sslkey and sslrootcert` arguments.

Comment: Still times out for me :(